# 3D rendering engine for python?

Tags: python, pygame, computer-vision, virtual-reality

I would like to make an application in which I somehow specify the 'architecture' of a virtual world (in terms of shapes, voxels, whatever), then a pinhole camera's 3D coordinates and the direction it is pointing, and it returns an image representing the rendering of the 3D world. Any suggestions? Bonus points if you can render simultaneously for two different pinhole cameras, representing your two eyes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest that it will take you a while to write something as good as [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org). :) And a 3D rendering system written in Python by someone who's not an expert in such things will be somewhat slower than one written in C that's been developed by a team of highly-skilled programmers over a couple of decades...

Comment: But if you _really_ want to do this, you'll need to create a language to specify your virtual world's architecture; write a parser for that language; and know enough 3D geometry / trigonometry to implement the required mathematics in your code.

Comment: OTOH, doing _simple_ 3D stuff in Python with stereo output isn't too hard. One way to handle the 3D transformations etc is to use [Homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). For starters, try to write a simple program that generates stereo pairs of a bunch wire frame cubes. If you get stuck, _show us your code_ and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: @PM2Ring Hi was wondering the same of JayHack. Just to figure out how it works. Is there any chance to get a ppt somewhere that explains in big terms how a softare like Pymol or Chimera works: their code is huge and cannot really understand it ?

Comment: @pippo1980 Sorry, I don't know much about Pymol or Chimera, but it's a huge task to write software like that. There are 2 aspects, creating the 3D scene description, and actually rendering the scene. The rendering side of things is the easy part. Sorry, I don't know of any relevant Python tutorials, but it's possible to do graphics at a reasonable speed in Python using Numpy to do most of the calculations. OTOH, the POVRay docs have a tutorial that shows how to create a raytracer in the POVRay SDL language. See https://www.povray.org/documentation/3.7.0/t2_3.html#t2_3_11

Answer (score 2):

If you want interactivity, you can use OpenGL if you install PyOpenGL. OpenGL is pretty low level, and takes a while to learn, but it is quite powerful. It is perfectly possible to render the same scene from two (or two hundred) different cameras using OpenGL, so there's that. However, you'll have to specify all the geometry that you want to render by drawing very simple shapes (really just lines, triangles, and rectangles)

The maker of PyOpenGL also has an additional module called "OpenGLContext" which takes care of some of the grungework for you; there are even tutorials at http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/index.html, and it includes scene-graph functionality, which will make specifying your scenes easier.

I've heard good things about Panda3D, OpenSceneGraph, and VPython, but haven't used them myself, and I don't know what support they have for stereoscopic rendering.

Good Luck!